# ElasticSearch Query search message and restrict to node id

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have the following mapping in ElasticSearch:

```
{
  "xenforo" : {
    "post" : {
      "_source" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "properties" : {
        "date" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "discussion_id" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "node" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "thread" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "user" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        }
      }
    },
```

I would like to search the message field for the word test but restrict it to node id 5. How would I modify this DSL search?

```
$data_string = '{
"from" : 0, "size" : 100,
"sort" : [
    { "date" : {"order" : "desc"} }
],
"query": {
        "match" : {
            "message" : {
                "query" : "test"
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

Thank you kindly for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filtered](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query/) query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [{
    "date": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "message": {
            "query": "test"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "node": 5
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One more question. If I want to use the same filtered query, but allow any number for the node, is there a value I can place instead of 5. For example "not null" ?

Comment: Would [exists](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/exists-filter/) filter work for you?

Comment: Sorry the exists filter wouldn't work.

If I can't use "not null" or some other term, I will just write additional code call the correct code.

Comment: One more question. What if I want to include node 5 but exclude node 10. Is that possible by using this filtered query?

Comment: exists should work. multiple filters can be combined by using [bool](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter/)  filter.